# What was the relationship between Ravan and Tadaka?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, rakshasa, genealogy

I remember watching some mythological in which Ravan calls Mareech his mama i.e. maternal uncle. But Mareech and Subahu were the sons of Tadka so does that make Ravan the grandson of Tadka?

I checked online and Tadka seems to have been married to an Asura called Sunda while Ravan's mother Kaikeshi was born to the rakshas Sumali. How can these two points be linked? Do the scriptures mention Sund and Sumali to be the same person?

Answer (score 2):

**Does that make Ravan the grandson of Tadka? Do the scriptures mention Sund and Sumali to be the same person?**

As per Valmiki Ramayana, NO:

Tataka was daughter of a **yaksha** named **Suketu**. She was married to **Jambha**'s son **Sunda**. Tataka and her son Mareecha attained demon-hood due to curse of sage Agastya. ~[Valmiki Ramayana: Bala Kanda: Sarga 25](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga25/bala_5F25_frame.htm)

On other hand Malyavan, Sumali, and Mali were sons of a demon named **Sukesa**. Their wives were Sundari, Ketumati, Gandharvi who were daughters of Narmada (a **Gandharvi**). And none of the children of Malyavanta, Sumali, and Mali was named Mareecha. 
**Malyavan**'s children were Vajramushti, Virupaksha, Durmukha, Suptaghna, Yajnakopa, Matta, Unmatta and Anala. **Sumali**'s children were Prahasta, Kampana, Vikata, Kalikamukha, Dhumraksha, Danda, Suparswa, Sanhradi, Praghasa, Bhasakarna, Pushpotkata, Kaikasi and Kumbhinasi. **Mali**'s children were Anala, Nila, and Sampati. ~[Valmiki Ramayana: Uttar Kanda: Sarga 5](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-5)

Comment: But then how is Mareech Ravan's uncle?

Comment: As per VRM, he is just Ravana's associate not mama....

Answer (score 1):

A small additional piece of information:

Mareecha (golden deer) was the servant of the 2 doorkeepers of Vaikuntha. He was reborn as a Rakshasa due to an emergency. As he cries 'Oh Lakshmana' and sees God Hari before dying, he ascends to Vaikuntha and once again takes up his earlier role [Ref: Devi Bhagavatam 9.16].